# What "phantom" means in javascriptcore compiler?

Tags: compiler-optimization, javascriptcore

In javascriptcore optimization compiler codes, there are some operations which has prefix "phantom".

For example, `PhantomNewArrayBuffer`, `PhantomNewObject`, `PhantomNewFunction`, etc).

I don't know what this prefix means.
Can anybody explain what this prefix stand for?

Comment: It's just part of the variable/function name.  You would need to examine the source to determine the intent of the developers.

Comment: I think they are PhantomJS API. PhantomJS is a headless Webkit.

Comment: @JinLee I think that's not. Because "Phantom" prefixed things are used in pure JavaScriptCore optimization compiler. I just guess it's like Phantom type in generic programming

Comment: Aha okay~~  :)b   Have a good day, bro!